# redirect to specific page after login based on browser language

Tags: php, redirect, lang

in my functions.php i have a redirect after login. currently this:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpdm_login_redirect' );
function wpdm_login_redirect(){
if( is_user_logged_in() && get_the_ID() == get_option('__wpdm_login_url') ):
    wp_redirect( home_url('/dashboard') );
    exit();
endif;
}
```

this works as expected, but i need to combine it with a redirect to a *different* page if the browser language is detected as italian, so an if ($lang=="it_IT") redirect to home_url('/area_personale'), and *everyone else* to '/dashboard'

i'm very new at this, so my problem is how to get this language stuff into my existing login redirect. or maybe there is an 'easier' way to go about this? any guidance most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpdm_login_redirect' );
function wpdm_login_redirect(){
$language = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

if( is_user_logged_in() && get_the_ID() == get_option('__wpdm_login_url') && $language == "it_IT" ):
    wp_redirect( home_url('/area_personale') );
    exit();

    else:

        wp_redirect( home_url('/dashboard') );

endif;
}
```

Comment: nope, this isn't working; site is trying to go straight to 'dashboard' without logging in, and /login is inaccessible - err_too_many_redirects. appreciate the help. could you have a look at this again?

Comment: try to add exit after the second redirect @wheeleran